# How can I connect to a database after its disk has come back online?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I have problems with database after reconnecting a hard disk:

1. .Net application works with database.
2. Disconnect hard disk with physical files.
3. Make any request to the database (of course we will have an exception, `Unable to open the physical file`).
4. Reconnect hard disk.
5. Any query to the database in the future will still throw an exception, `Unable to open the physical file`.

How can I recover connection with physical files without restarting the SQL Server service?

Comment: what is the purpose of doing this ? You might end up corrupting the databases.

Comment: purpose is recover connection. It happens from time to time because the database is actually located on the remote disk.

Comment: Why do you have a database on a remote disk? This is exactly why you shouldn't. Did you see what state your database is in after this incident? If it is `OFFLINE` try `ALTER DATABASE foo SET ONLINE;` - however don't be surprised if it goes into `SUSPECT` or worse - GET A REAL DISK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. First, tell your customer to get a real disk. Using a remote disk this way is exactly why you are having difficulty at this stage, and it *could* very well lead to a corrupt / unrecoverable database. You are rolling the dice every time this drive goes offline, even if only temporarily.
2. Next, check the status of the database:

   ```
   USE master;
   GO
   SELECT state_desc 
     FROM sys.databases
     WHERE name = N'your_database';
   ```

   If this if `OFFLINE`, and you're sure the drive is available, run:

   ```
   ALTER DATABASE your_database SET ONLINE;
   ```

   Now, this might not work - as I suggested the database could come up `SUSPECT` or it might not come online at all.
3. If / when it does come back online, take a full backup. Schedule these (and/or log backups if in full recovery) to run much more frequently, to cover your butt.
4. Tell your customer to get a real disk. This may work in the short term but this is a ticking time bomb.

Comment: I checked a database state. It's RECOVERY_PENDING.

Comment: @Avant Did you delete the log file? If you can't get it online, restore to a recent backup. If you don't have a recent backup, that's strike two; you need to advise your customer to make better decisions. If you are stuck here see Paul's posts: [Using EMERGENCY mode to access a RECOVERY PENDING or SUSPECT database](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/search-engine-qa-4-using-emergency-mode-to-access-a-recovery-pending-or-suspect-database/) and [Emergency mode repair - the last resort](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/checkdb-from-every-angle-emergency-mode-repair-the-very-very-last-resort/)